# Subring of all elements represented by quotients of function field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $K_C$ is the function field of a curve $C$ and $p \in C$. Let $\mathcal{O}_k \subset K_C$ be the subring of all elements represented by quotients $G/H$ where $G, H \in \mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$ are homogeneous of the same degree, and $H(p) \neq 0$. What does this look like/how can I visualize this?

For starters, I've observed that any element of $K_C$ can be interpreted as function on $C - H^{-1}(0)$. So $\mathcal{O}_p$ is those functions which are defined at $p$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have edited my post as to say what they are.

Comment: $C$ is a plane curve?